# How can I iterate over folders and Merge all files in them using data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have Folders in a Year , Month , Day fashion stored in Datalake as given below. I want to merge all files from a particular Month using ADF.

- Month

  - 01

    - File1
    - File2
  - 02

    - File3
    - File4

Is it possible to achieve this in ADF ?

Edit 1 - I need to merge all the files in Month to one single Output file.
In above case File 1,File 2,File 3 and File 4 will be merged as One single file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this by Copy activity.

1. create Source and use Wildcard paths to specify the files you want to copy.
   [image]

2.choose `Merge files` option in Sink.
[image]

3.you can define your output file name here.
[image]

---

**Update:**
[image]

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for the Answer. But it seems you misunderstood the question, here you are merging files of 1 day from a Month which is pretty straightforward. But I want to retrieve files for all Days in a Month and Merge the. So in above case, all File1, File2, File3, File4 will be merges as One output File.

Comment: @noobCoder50 You can just change wildcard folder path to `Month` is ok.